# VBA Select Multiple Tabs in Spreadsheet using code

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, worksheet

I have a spreadsheet with 3 tabs. I need the following code to select the first two tabs. I almost have it but the `Sheets(Array(c)).Select` portion returns an error. Essentially i need the last section to return as Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

```
Sub HideUnhide2()
Dim a As String
Dim b As Double
Dim c As String
Application.Calculation = xlManual
        For I = 1 To 100
            If Range("d5") <> "Entity:" Then Exit For
            'Start
            c = c & ", " & Chr(34) & ActiveSheet.Name & Chr(34)


            'End
            b = b + 1

            ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        Next I
    '   End If
           c = Right(c, Len(c) - 2)
           MsgBox c
           Sheets(Array(c)).Select

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
MsgBox "Total tabs updated = " & b

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you need them selected? Do you do something on each of the selected sheets?

Comment: Learn the macro recorder. Use the macro recorder. Love the macro recorder. That is the greatest gift I can give you.

Comment: @Slai yes i multiple spreadsheets with tabs that are basically mirror image of each other. I need to select all and update.

Comment: Then you can update them without selecting them. I don't see the need to select them.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Sub SelectTabs()

    Dim numSheets As Integer
    numSheets = 5
    Dim aSheets() As String
    ReDim aSheets(numSheets - 1)

    For i = 0 To numSheets - 1
        aSheets(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i + 1).Name
    Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(aSheets()).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: The code i posted is a reduced version of a complex loop that needs to be used in multiple spreadsheets with different number of tabs. Basically i need the code to check to see if a tab has value "Entity:" in cell D5 and if yes then select it along with all other tabs that meet this criteria. The solution you proposed works if the number of tabs are always fixed, but may not work if the number continues to changes. See my original post i modified the simple version with the full code.

Comment: @BillSingh I don't think "spreadsheet" means what you think it does. The object model calls them `Workbook`; a `Worksheet` is a "tab" in a "spreadsheet".

Comment: @Mat'sMug i am not following. Can you please elaborate? My issue really lies in how to pass a string to an array and the issue lies in the last line in the code Sheets(Array(c)).Select. Let me know if you have a perspective on this.

Comment: @BillSingh You say "spreadsheet" to refer to `Workbook`, but "sheet" is an API concept that refers to a `Worksheet`. I'm saying your choice of words is confusing, you should use the terms used by the API so that everyone understands your meaning unambiguously.

Comment: @SEarle1986 Can you modify this code so that it loops from worksheet currently selected and moves to the right?

Comment: Your requirements keep changing. Please update the question show it read exactly what you need, not some of it. 
Should the current selected sheet remain selected? How many sheets to the right should be selected?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Worksheet.Select` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-select-method-excel) lets you specify if want to add to or replace the current selection:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet, replaceSelection As Boolean
replaceSelection = True

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Range("d5") = "Entity:" Then
       ws.Select Replace:=replaceSelection
       replaceSelection = False
    End If
Next
```

To select starting from the current Sheet:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet, replaceSelection As Boolean
replaceSelection = True

While Not ws Is Nothing
    If ws.Range("d5") = "Entity:" Then
       ws.Select Replace:=replaceSelection
       replaceSelection = False
    End If
    Set ws = ws.Next
Wend
```

Comment: If i try to execute the second code it asks for which Macro i want to execute. I get a pop-up box which has a list of all macros. What am i doing wrong? I have this code stored in the Module of the spreadsheet.

Comment: @BillSingh VBA can't guess which macro you want to run unless the cursor is in the method